# Android Studio app icon not showing in new Android models

Tags: android-studio

I have a simple app in Android Studio. I've changed the app icons from default (all of them, all sizes, with the round ones too). It works on the emulator and on Samsung Galaxy S2, but not in newer models (like Galaxy J7). Perhaps someone knows why?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,
Adi.

Comment: Would You Please Attach photo to make us sure how it looks?

Comment: It shows:https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRdCUd0uE-KeRbggAMtDE4S6FcUtWdCNgJVbw&usqp=CAU instead of my icon

Answer (score 0):

I just followed this instructions:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-the-default-icon-of-android-app/

and all works fine.

Greetings,
Adi